# Is there an R function for extracting text pattern using logical operators

Tags: r

I am new to programming, so I appreciate any help. I have several string documents, and I want to know if some keywords happen in these documents, but in combination with other words, and in some cases, ignoring some words.

For example, if I consider the following data, I would like to find all documents where **“Rains & Germany”** happen together.

`list_documents <- c("it rains in Germany", "it rains a lot in the field" , "the sun is shining in Germany")`

The output would be something like

```
[1] TRUE
[2] FALSE
[3] FALSE
```

Does anyone know which package should I use for that? I tried “str_extract”, but the logical operators do not work on text.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `str_extract` is for extracting substrings, you should use `str_detect` or `grepl` from base package.

Comment: is your research goal Natural Language Processing?

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep` function:

```
grepl('rains', list_documents, ignore.case = T) & grepl('germany', list_documents, ignore.case = T)

# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

OR

```
grepl('rains.*germany|germany.*rains', list_documents, ignore.case = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Reduce` solution.

```
patterns <- c("Rains", "Germany")
Reduce('&', lapply(patterns, function(x) grepl(x, list_documents, ignore.case = TRUE)))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

It works by first creating a list of logical vectors, each of them with the result of `grepl`applied to each of the patterns. Then `Reduce` AND's the list's members in pairs.

Note that the above solution still works if there are more than 2 patterns to search for and AND. The one-liner can be made a function, this time separating the list creation and the `Reduce`.

```
and_grepl <- function(pattern, x, ...){
  results <- lapply(pattern, function(p) grepl(p, x, ...))
  Reduce('&', results)
}

and_grepl(patterns, list_documents, ignore.case = TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

pat <- c("A", "B", "C")
new_list <- c("ABCD", "ABCE", "ABDE", "DEFG")
and_grepl(pat, new_list)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```